# how to catch error on mariadb for connection timeout in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mariadb, try-catch

I come to resort where connection is unreliable and noticed my try catch blocks are not working in mariadb, nodejs, so application brutally dies. I want to catch error and gracefully return error message.

```
try{
  pool = mariadb.createPool(dbParams);
  pool.on("error", err => {
          console.log('Mysql error dbParams', dbParams.host)
          console.log(err); 
      })
  }catch(e){
      console.log('dbParams', dbParams.host)
      console.log(e)
  }
```

And app dies in this function in the try block:

```
async function dbQuery(...args){
  let result = false;
  try{
    result = pool.query(...args)
  }catch(e){
    console.log('query icinde yakalandi', e)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Error is this:

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms
    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)
    at module.exports.createError (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/mariadb@3.1.1/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:57:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/mariadb@3.1.1/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:344:26)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 From event:
    at ConnectionPromise._PARAM (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/mariadb@3.1.1/node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection-promise.js:104:30)
    at PoolPromise.query (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/mariadb@3.1.1/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool-promise.js:100:40)
    at IncomingMessage.dbQuery (/app/config.js:40:19)
    at /app/index.js:166:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /app/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at param (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/express@4.18.2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14) {
  text: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms\n' +
    '    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)',
  sql: null,
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use mariadb but there could be a potential issue with your code that might be causing the problem. I beleive the error is being thrown inside the pool.query() function, and since this function is asynchronous(I am assuming), its errors cannot be caught directly using a try-catch block within dbQuery. To gracefully handle the error, you need to await for the promise and then be able to catch and handle the error.

```
async function dbQuery(...args) {
  try {
    const result = await pool.query(...args)
    return result
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('query icinde yakalandi', e)
    throw e // Rethrow the error to be caught at the higher level if needed.
  }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right, after awaiting I catched it. So new knowledge has ben acquired.